# Change default Python interpreter for Kivy from 2.7 to 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I read that since Kivy 1.8 I can you Python 3.3 instead of 2.7 but although I have Python 3.3 installed the `kivy` command still uses `2.7`.

Can I manually modify `kivy` bash script and change the last line `exec $(python -c "import os, sys; ...` to point to my Python 3.3 installation? There's a [similar question about Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929345/using-kivy-with-python-3-4) but this should not be supported right now.

So, what's the recommended way?

Comment: Give us more details, kivy runs on a lot of platforms, which platform, os version are you using? Did you compile kivy or use the pre-built packages, if you used the pre-built packages did you use the packages for python3.x?

Comment: I installed Kivy against Python 3.4 using a virtualenv. With a virtualenv,`python` will call the correct version.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that I'm running OS X. I looked again into download section on Kivy website and there's package with Python 3.3 for Windows but not for OS X, so it's probably not supported right not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kivy packages for OSX use the default system Python: 2.7. All the dependencies we've compiled are based on the ABI of system Python 2.7.

Using another Python, or 3.3, will just not work. Python is great when you stay in pure python, but we are using lot of underlaying libraries, which requires compilation too. We'll try to release a 3.4 version somehow.

Comment: At this time, for Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LT is there or isn't there a way to install Kivy with 3.3/3.4? 

The Kivy Installation and Android APK requirements are hopefully allowing Python 3.3+. As one who learned Python with 3.x and using the 3.4 API regularly, I'd really lose the interest to use Kivy.